# embeding video into HTML

Tags: html, html5-video

so I'm trying to create an HTML page that includes an MP4 file, yet it displays that there is an "unknown error" I tried different codes and all gave the same result, what would you recommend?

```
<embed src="try.mp4" autoplay> <video width="1200" height="700" controls>
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide your code please.
Check this link too : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<video src="(your path to video)">
```

Try this. Double chack your path to your video if it doesn't work.

Comment: i will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

```html
<video src="Your path of video" width="320" height="240" controls>
```

- Example:-

```
<video src="https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1595743746~acl=%2A%2F572326125.mp4%2A~hmac=c790f78538cb5846102b4d081e72207e8d7d20161268086d7526ef9b96cb9062/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/255/7/176277723/572326125.mp4?filename=Beach+-+3998.mp4" controls width="640">
```